# Application_Start not behaving correctly in ASP.Net 4.0 Application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, global-asax, application-start

I'm stumped. I ran through all the recommendations on StackOverflow and Google... no joy.

My Application_Start method is not behaving correctly in my ASP.Net 4.0 application.  I can set Application variables, but not call my logging method.

I can set variables:

```
Application["appStartDT"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

But my logging method is not called:

```
Utilities.writeLog("Application started at: " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString(), 4);
```

This happened about the time I switched from the internal IIS server in VWDE 2010 to IIS 7.5 (On Windows 7), though I'm not 100% it's related (had to switch, as I was using virtual directories).

[Post Script Edit: I switched to project back to "Use Visual Studio Development Server" and my Application_Start method fired and executed my logging method.  I need to use IIS.  Any suggestion on what IIS setting I am overlooking?]

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Respectfully,

Ray

Comment: To access Application variables, you need to use brackets -- Application["appStartDT"] = DateTime.Now;  Not sure about your Start event unfortunately.

Comment: @o6tech, yep, you're exactly right.  Typo on my part, but still have underlying problem.  Thanks!

Comment: what does '4' mean in the writeLog method? Also, can you try the same in Release mode & see if it gets logged?

Comment: Are you able to set a breakpoint on the WriteLog method and run in debug mode? What happens if you step into the method?

Comment: @SoftwareGeek, 4 is the logging level, so I can varying levels of verbosity in my logs.

Comment: @Brian, I put a breakpoint in my writeLog method and the application flew right by it.  As I recall there's a problem with breakpoints in the Application_Start method, something about it firing before the debug can hook into it (I did a lot of research before posting).

Comment: What anonymous identity are you running the site under? Specific user or Application Pool identity? You can find this out by opening the Authentication applet for the site in IIS manager then right clicking on Anonymous Authentication and selecting Edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think one difference with switching to IIS is that the IIS process that your website is running under will now be the [local machine]\Network Service account. I am assuming that your `Utilities.writeLog` method is writing something out to a file. If that in fact is the case, then you should check that the Network Service account has read/write privileges to the file and folder where you are logging. I have experienced this same issue with log4Net logging output to a file and when I gave the Network Service account access to the folder/file I was logging to, the issue went away.

Comment: Utilities.writeLog() works everywhere else, including in other methods within Global.asax.cs. To verify, I added Network Service, with write permissions, but it still didn't write when called in Application_Start. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: you will not hit breakpoint,debugger is not loaded at application start event, it comes much later. did u try release mode?