# ASP.NET MVC3 Debugging Application_Start

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I am trying to deploy my first MVC3 application to a server running IIS-7.5.  I've got the thing up and running, but I'm having some trouble with my debugging methods.  I use a proprietary debugging construct that works just fine when I run the application locally (using the built in "IIS Express" module and Visual Studio) - but when I deploy to the server, I don't even get my debug file created, much less printed to.

The debugging file is created in the Application_Start event, so I put an event log stamping in the Application_Start event and ran the application locally and on the server, just to see if the event is getting fired.  My event logs locally were stamped to as intended, but the event logs on the server are bare of any new stamping.  What's going on here?

```
protected void Application_Start()
  {
     AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

//This is just some code that calls to another module I wrote to easily stamp to the Event logs - it works, trust me
     EventLogging.Initialize();
     EventLogging.WriteEventLog("Application Start Called Successfully");
  }
```

Comment: by 'debug file' are you talking event log entries (which would require permissions on the event log from your app pool identity) as opposed to a physical file?

Comment: @AdamTuliper Sorry for the ambiguity - "debug file", in the phrase above, refers to a physical file.  However, I am able to write to neither the physical file nor the event logs.  Let me try adding my Application Identity Pool directly to the Event Log Permissions...

Comment: @AdamTuliper Ok, I added the AppPool Identity to the ACL for the EventLogs directly in the registry editor - still nothing... =(  Perhaps I have a more basic problem?  ::sigh::

Comment: is this completely proprietary logging? is there any dynamic assembly loading? log4net for example will use debug output (you can see this with dbgview). Does this logger do any of this?

Comment: @AdamTuliper Yes, it's completely proprietary.  But, it's working now, see below.  =)

Comment: weird - the ole 'republish and problems go away' issue : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS 7.5 uses virtual accounts for the application pools.

See [App Pool Identities](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/).  Make sure the specific app pool identity has access to the appropriate folder to read/write.

Comment: That is quite interesting!  I was able to add my app pool identity to the permissions listing (ACL), but still no file.  I don't know how to change permissions on the event logs so that this account can write to them - I think any account should be able to do that though...

Comment: Update -- I was able to add my AppPool Identity to the Event Logs permissions ACL via the registry editor, but still nothing.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351608/application-start-not-behaving-correctly-in-asp-net-4-0-application.  The poster claims that their logging works everywhere except application start, is that the same for you?

Comment: I found this article on attaching a debugger in the application_start... haven't tried it but it might help you.  http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/Dec/15/Debugging-ApplicationStart-and-Module-Initialization-with-IIS-and-Visual-Studio

Comment: Ok, this was definitely a big part of it, but I still had issues after doing this.  In the end, I had to pull the code off the server and re-publish.  Suddenly, it works...  =(

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem you're running into is the IIS process is run under the Network Service account.  By default this account only has read and execute permissions to the IIS root folder.  Hence any attempts to write to the local file system will fail.

To make this work you'll need to give the Network Service account explicit write access to the file in question.  This can be done via Windows Explorer.

- Right Click on the file and select properties
- Go to the security tab
- Add write access for the Network Service account

Comment: I have added the Network Service to the securities listing for the website parent folder and propagated permissions to all child objects - no dice.  =(

Comment: @C.Barlow have you checked the event log or attached a debugger?  It sounds like something else is going on then

Comment: The event logs aren't showing anything.  Unfortunately, given that this event is the first thing that fires, I don't know how to attach a debugger before it runs through...

Comment: @C.Barlow add a `Debugger.Break` call as your first statement in the method.

Comment: also as @CtrlDot pointed out you may need to give access to a different account in IIS7 than previous versions.

Comment: Were you expecting I should receive a popup about attaching the debugger?  I did not see one on the server machine.  I did follow CtrlDot's link to the article on Application Pool Identities, see my comment on his post - no luck there either, unfortunately.